# Have a PCWSTR and need it to be a WCHAR[]

Tags: c++, string, winapi, wchar-t, lpcwstr

I am re-writing a C++ method from some code I downloaded. The method originally took a PCWSTR as a parameter and then prompted the user to enter a file name. I modified the method to take two parameters (both PCWSTR) and not to prompt the user. I am already generating the list of files somewhere else. I am attempting to call my new (modified) method with both parameters from my method that iterates the list of files.

The original method prompted the user for input using a StringCBGetsW command. Like this...

```
HRESULT     tst=S_OK;         //these are at the top of the method
WCHAR       fname[85] = {0};  //these are at the top of the method
tst = StringCbGetsW(fname,sizeof(fname));
```

The wchar **fname** gets passed to another iteration method further down. When I look at that method, it says it's a **LPCWSTR** type; I'm assuming it can take the **WCHAR** instead.

But what it can't do is take the **PCWSTR** that the method got handed. My ultimate goal is to try not prompt the user for the file name and to take instead the filename that was iterated earlier in another method.

tl;dr. I have a PCWSTR and it needs to get converted to a WCHAR. I don't know what a WCHAR [] is or how to do anything with it. Including to try to do a **printf** to see what it is.

PS...I know there are easier ways to move and copy around files, there is a reason I'm attempting to make this work using a program.

Comment: `LPCWSTR` is the same thing as `PCWSTR`.

Comment: IIRC that horrible hungarian notation denotes for a `PCWSTR` as a pointer to a const `WCHAR` literal. You probably need to dereference it to access `WCHAR`'s.

Comment: `WCHAR[]` is implicitly convertible to `PCWSTR`; can you show code instead of describing it, so that we can see where the real issue is? In other words, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Look at the definition of `LPCWSTR`, it's the same as `const WCHAR *`. If you know how pointers and arrays interact that should be all you need.

Comment: If you "don't know what a `WCHAR []` is", you should probably pick up a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, let's try to make some clarity on some **Windows specific types**.

**`WCHAR`** is a typedef for `wchar_t`.
On Windows with Microsoft Visual C++, it's a *16-bit character type* (that can be used for Unicode UTF-16 strings).

**`PCWSTR`** and **`LPCWSTR`** are two different names for the same thing: they are basically `typedef`s for **`const wchar_t*`**.

The initial `L` in `LPCWSTR` is some legacy prefix that, read with the following `P`, stands for *"long pointer"*. I've never programmed Windows in the 16-bit era (I started with Windows 95 and Win32), but my understanding is that in 16-bit Windows there were something like *near pointers* and *far, or long pointers*. Now we have just one type of pointers, so the `L` prefix can be omitted.

The `P` stands for *"pointer"*.
The `C` stands for *"constant"*.
The `W` stands for `WCHAR`/`wchar_t`, and last but not least, the `STR` part stands for *"string"*.

So, decoding this kind of "Hungarian Notation", `PCWSTR` means `const wchar_t*`.
Basically, it's a pointer to a read-only `NUL`-terminated `wchar_t` Unicode UTF-16 string.

Is this information enough for you to solve your problem?

If you have a `wchar_t` string buffer, and a function that expects a `PCWSTR`, you can just pass the name of the buffer (corresponding the the address of its first character) to the function:

```
WCHAR buffer[100];
DoSomething(buffer, ...);  // DoSomething(PCWSTR ....)
```

Sometimes - typically for *output* string parameters - you may also want to specify the size (i.e. "capacity") of the destination string buffer.
If this size is expressed using a count in characters (in this case, in `wchar_t`s), the the usual Win32 Hungarian Notation is *`cch`* (*"count of characters"*); else, if you want the size expressed in bytes, then the usual prefix is *`cb`* (*"count of bytes"*).
So, if you have a function like `StringCchCopy()`, then from the `Cch` part you know the size is expressed in characters (`wchar_t`s).

Note that you can use **`_countof()`** to get the size of a buffer in `wchar_t`s.
e.g. in the above code snippet, `_countof(buffer) == 100`, since `buffer` is made by 100 `wchar_t`s; instead, `sizeof(buffer) == 200`, since each `wchar_t` is 2 bytes == 16 bits in size, so the total buffer size in bytes is `100 [wchar_t] * 2 [bytes/wchar_t] = 200 [bytes]`.

Comment: Thanks; this makes the most sense out of any explanation of all these data types and what to do with them.